# pandas: map series to list (not dict)

Tags: python, pandas

I want the most pythonic way to do this. The series contains integers which reflect positions in a list of values.

This works but needs a dictionary for arbitrary index:

```
df = pd.Series([0,1,2,3])
dx = {0: 'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d'}
df.map(dx)
```

This also works but needs a lambda funciton:

```
df = pd.Series([0,1,2,3])
dx = ['a','b', 'c','d']
df.apply(lambda x: dx[x])
```

Is there a way to index the list without a lambda function? (i.e. map but accepting a list)

Comment: *to index the list* - list is already indexed structure

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`__getitem__`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__getitem__-in-python/) (fairly generic access slot in Python):

```py
df = pd.Series([0,1,2,3])
dx = ['a','b', 'c','d']
df.apply(dx.__getitem__)
```

Comment: cool good suggestion. is there something without using apply?

Comment: You can use `map` instead of `apply`

Comment: df.map(dx.__getitem__) :thumnsup:

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can build your dictionary on the fly with `enumerate` and `dict`:

```
df = pd.Series([0,1,2,3])
dx = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
out = df.map(dict(enumerate(dx)))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3])
dx = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
result = [dx[x] for x in df]
```

The code takes a series of numbers and a list of letters. It then creates a new list where each number in the series is replaced by the corresponding letter from the list.

Comment: This works but returns a list not a series.